# Using PyTorch on AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytorch

Has anyone had any luck being able to use PyTorch on AWS Lambda for feature extraction from images or just using the framework at all? I finally got PyTorch, numpy, and pillow zipped in a folder under the uncompressed size limit (which is actually around 262 MB) but I had to build PyTorch from source to do this. The problem I am having now is that Lambda has a very old version of gcc running on it (4.8.3) which is very buggy and [missing whole header files](https://medium.com/@Inoryy/compiling-pytorch-4-0-on-ubuntu-17-10-with-cuda-9-0-and-python-3-6-6769a0df56d5) altogether. I believe the Pytorch docs state you should be using at least gcc 7 or later but I'm hoping someone may have found a way around this? I built the source using gcc 7.5 but then when I tried to import torch Lambda obviously used it's installed version of 4.8.3 causing an error on import: `Floating point exception (core dumped)` which stems from the old version of gcc. Is there a possible solution around this? I've been at this for a day and a half now so any help would be great. I think the bottom line is I am facing this similar [issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=284016). Better yet does anyone have a Pytorch lambda layer I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to utilize the below layers for using `pytorch` on `AWS Lambda`:

```
arn:aws:lambda:AWS_REGION:934676248949:layer:pytorchv1-py36:1   PyTorch 1.0.1
arn:aws:lambda:AWS_REGION:934676248949:layer:pytorchv1-py36:2   PyTorch 1.1.0
```

Found these on [Fastai](https://course.fast.ai/deployment_aws_lambda.html) production deployment page, thanks to [Matt McClean](https://github.com/mattmcclean)

Comment: If you want to create your own layer you can i) download the relevant wheel (whl) file from the pypi download link (for linux); ii) unzip and re-zip the content, putting it in a folder called python in the zip file; and iii) upload it as a layer directly or via s3 if its bigger than 50mb.